# Managing array of monads in fp-ts and Functional Programming

Tags: arrays, typescript, functional-programming, monads, fp-ts

I'm very new to Functional Programming and I'm struggling a lot with running traverse on arrays.

When I read [this book](https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide) it seems that I should be able to simply traverse between Monads but I can't wrap my head around this concept with [fp-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/).

Can someone explain the following using `array.traverse/sequence` or any other ways please?

1. How can I go from `TaskEither<Error, string[]>` to `TaskEither<Error, Either<Error, string>[]>`; or is there a better way to go from a single error to nested errors while keeping the typings simple?
2. How can I go from `TaskEither<Error, Either<Error, string[]>>` to something like `TaskEither<Error, Option<string[]>>` or something similar; or should we map the result of that function to turn back to `Either`?

Consider the following simplified code to have a better idea what we are doing with these arrays:

```
// helper functions
declare function toItems(input: string): TaskEither<Error, string[]);
declare function toTitle(item: string): Either<Error, string>;
declare function clean(item: string): Option<string>;

// This is what I tried so far
const program = (input: string) => pipe(
  toItems(input), // we have TaskEither<Error, string[]>
  TE.map(items => array.traverse(either)(items, toTitle)), // now we have TaskEither<Error, Either<Error, string[]>>
  TE.map(items => array.traverse(option)(items, clean)), // nothing works with clean() from here
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strictly spoken, [Applicative](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/12c5f51e551b4b1a382e936565ebf0b8f1338d9c/src/ReadonlyArray.ts#L1435) is sufficient for `traverse` - you don't need a monad.

> `TaskEither<Error, string[]>` to `TaskEither<Error, Either<Error, string>[]>`?

```
const program1 = (input: string) =>
  P.pipe(
    toItems(input),
    TE.map(A.map(toTitle))
  );
```

> `TaskEither<Error, Either<Error, string[]>>` to `TaskEither<Error, Option<string[]>>`?

```
const program2 = (input: string) =>
  P.pipe(
    toItems(input),
    TE.map(items => A.array.traverse(O.option)(items, clean))
  );
```

The concrete chosen structure depends your environment and purpose. ▶ `Option`: emphasis on absence/presence ; ▶ `Either`: permits a more concrete error type in `Left`.

---

Let's look at some programs and imagine, all use a web API with `TaskEither`.

Program 3: `(input: string) => TE.TaskEither<Error, string[]>`

▶ will either fail *completely* with `Error` or succeed with `string[]` fetched data

Program 4: `(input: string) => TE.TaskEither<Error, E.Either<Error, string[]>>`

▶ `fetch` results in `Error` or succeeds. If succeeded, process web data further - resulting in `Error` *or* `string[]`

Program 5: `(input: string) => TE.TaskEither<Error, E.Either<Error, string>[]>`

▶ same as Program 4, but post-processing of web data results in *multiple* `Either` results - each can fail or succeed *individually*

---

Here is implementation of program 4 as some kind of middle ground:

```
const program4 = (
  input: string
): TE.TaskEither<Error, E.Either<Error, string[]>> =>
  P.pipe(
    toItems(input), // TE.TaskEither<Error, string[]>
    TE.map(items => // TE.TaskEither<E, E.Either<Error, string[]>>
      A.array.traverse(E.either)( // E.Either<Error, string[]>
        items,
        F.flow( // E.Either<Error, string>
          toTitle,
          E.chain(s => E.fromOption(() => Error())(clean(s)))
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-61133166-2owex)

Comment: Thank you so much @ford04. Do you recommend any source to read more about these concepts to master them?
I think I understand when I see the code but I struggle to get there on my own.

Comment: For `fp-ts` in particular, I found the [Getting started](https://dev.to/gcanti/getting-started-with-fp-ts-setoid-39f3) series and other articles by author Giulio Canti quite useful for a deeper understanding. Besides that, just experiment with the code examples you get :-). Unfortunately, `fp-ts` doesn't work in the TS playground (yet), so I use to link a sandbox here. You also can find really good articles in JS + other languages for more general fp concepts, so might be worth to be open for it.