# Getting the first successful value in an array of TaskEithers

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, monads, either, fp-ts

I'm relatively new to functional programming and very new to [fp-ts](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/), so I'm having a struggle wrapping my head around the util functions provided. I'm currently trying to figure out how to handle `TaskEither`s as fallbacks in an array.

I have a function to fetch data for some `id`, that returns `Error` or `Success`:

```
declare function getData(id: number): TaskEither<Error, Success>
```

What I want is a function that will iterate through some array of `id`s (ex. `[1, 2, 3, 4]`), requesting data for each one. It should stop at the first `TaskEither` that succeeds and return `Right<Success>`. If all of the `TaskEither`s fail, it should collect their errors into a `Left<Error[]>`.

```
import { map } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';

const program: TaskEither<Error[], Success>
  = pipe(
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    map(getData),
    /*
     * Now I have a TaskEither<Error, Success>[]
     * What comes next?
     */
  );
```

I tried something similar, but there are some obvious problems (noted below):

```
import { map, sequence } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';
import { map as mapTaskEither } from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither'

const program: TaskEither<Error, Success>
  = pipe(
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    map(getData),
    sequence(taskEither), // Now this gets to a TaskEither<Error, Success[]>
    mapTaskEither(successes => successes[0])
  );
```

Problems with this approach

1. It runs `getData` on all of the IDs, without short-circuiting on the first success
2. It errors if *any* of the `getData`s errors. So if `getData(4)` errors, the overall `program` will error even if `getData(1)` succeeded
3. It does not collect the errors into an array of `Error[]`

Comment: I found a very good answer to a similar question, but I'm having an extremely hard time wrapping my head around al the layers of abstractions in functional programming. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133166/managing-array-of-monads-in-fp-ts-and-functional-programming

Comment: I'll let someone who is more familiar with fp-ts in particular give a full answer, but I believe you'll have to implement your own function (or your own Traversable instance for TaskEither) if you want to retain the Left=Error convention. If you make Right=Error, I think your code meets your requirements.

Comment: Oh that's a great insight. It gives me the idea to just do something like: ..., map(swap), sequence(taskEither), swap ... I'll try putting this into its own function so it can just be consolidated for readability. I'll post an answer to this question if it works. Great idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this insightful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765483/getting-the-first-successful-value-in-an-array-of-taskeithers/62785614#comment110997545_62765483), I've come up a solution.

It helps with readability to give this util function a name:

```
import { TaskEither, taskEither, swap } from 'fp-ts/lib/TaskEither';
import { sequence, map } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';
import { pipe } from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

const firstRightOrLefts: <A, B>(taskEithers: TaskEither<A, B>[]) => TaskEither<A[], B>
    = taskEithers => pipe(
        taskEithers,
        map(swap),
        sequence(taskEither),
        swap,
    );
```

And then it can be used like this:

```
import { map } from 'fp-ts/lib/Array';

const program: TaskEither<Error, Success>
  = pipe(
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    map(getData),
    getFirstRightOrLefts, // <-- Woohoo!
  );
```